# When finding the shortest distance between a point and a line, why omit the position vector from the line equation when using the dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have line l1 and point p. The shortest distance is  the line segment from p to the line that is perpendicular to the line. We find this line segment and define it by the line equation - p. We then use the dot product set to 0. but we multiply the line segment by only the direction vector part of the line equation. This is the part I don't understand. I have tried using the full equation of the line in the dot product and I end up with a quadratic with an extra solution.

Comment: Your description is a little unclear (to me). It would help if you would work through a specific example.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understanding your question, but setting the dot product of two vectors equal to 0 gives when the vectors are perpendicular. Since the dot product is desired to be 0, the magnitude is irrelevant, so a unit direction vector would suffice.

Comment: Ok, I do not know how to do vector notation on here though, apologies. We have a line with vector equation r=(2,-1,3)+lambda(1,2,1) and point P with coordinates (3,0,2) To find the shortest distance between the point and the line, we create a linne segment PM, where M is a point on the line. PM= the P coordinates- the line vector equation. We then dot PM with the direction vector of the line equation and set it to 0, and solve for the lambda scalar to find the coordinates of M. I do not understand why we dont use the full line equation including the position vector part.

Comment: You want $PM$ to be perpendicular to the line, so your first factor of the dot product is the vector that represents $PM$ and the second factor of the dot product is the direction vector of the line. If you put the full line equation as second factor, you would force $PM$ to be perpendicular to $OM$ which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Reinhard Meier: Ok I can see why just the direction vector work. Its just 2 general directions that could be anywhere in relation to the origin. If we take the position vector of the line, it feels like this would just connect ourselves in space to the origin with these directions. I cannot see why it would be OM  that PM becomes perpendicular too?